# Finding the max points of a surface, maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

This should not be hard at all, in fact no one seems so be having my issue so it should be me missing out on a point of information or just experience.

My mission is to with **Mathematica** find the x,y,z's of the maximum points of the following function

$$\left[\frac{-\left(1-x^2\right) \left(y^2-4\right)-x^2-y^2+5}{\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)^2}\right]$$

Currently I am trying with Maximize

$Maximize[\left[\frac{-\left(1-x^2\right) \left(y^2-4\right)-x^2-y^2+5}{\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)^2}\right], {x,y,z}]$

[image: image of the surface]

I can't make heads or tails of this answer though, so I am doing something wrong.., finding the points for reference I did with wolfram.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max%20(-(x%5E2-1)*(y%5E2%20-%204)%20-%20x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%20%2B%205)%2F(x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%201)%5E2)   gives me the points

$$\left\{\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},0,\frac{9}{8}\right\}$$

How do I use for example maximize[] or some other simple function in Mathematica to find those values? I have set the partial derivatives to 0 and solved for the points, that works but seems to me to be overly complicated.

The documentation has me confused, it does this and gets three values, I try to do the same and I get something strange

Manual:

[image: manual]

My answer, which is to my eyes wrong:

[image: my answer]

Even if I try to use //NN I get strange answers:

[image: strange answers]

I kind of do get the x coordinate if I do this but why this is the case I don't know.

$Maximize[\left[\frac{-\left(1-x^2\right) \left(y^2-4\right)-x^2-y^2+5}{\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)^2}\right], {y,z}]$

I have also tried to use FindMaximum and FindMaxValue.

This baffles me, any ideas, it should be simple right? Why don't I get the points? is it because there are two extreme points perhaps?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Ok, cool,  thanks Michael

Answer (score 1):

I think it's only a question of accolades

```
Maximize[(-(1 - x^2) (y^2 - 4) - x^2 - y^2 + 5)/(x^2 + y^2 + 1)^2, {x,y}]
```

return

> {9, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}

Comment: Hum, accolades?, "an award or an expression of praise" merriam webster.

I do know the points already through wolfram,  but I cant transfer that to mathematica since I dont have wolfPRO

$\left\{+-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},0,\frac{9}{8}\right\}$ should be the solutions, what am I not getting from your answer?

Comment: @Celebrin  Why not get the points through *Mathematica* instead of W|A?

Comment: Well that is what I hoped to do, and the question asked, .  I have since calculated the points through partial derivatives..  but there should be an easier way.

you got any idea Michael?

Comment: @Celebrin. I think cyrille means "brackets". You need to remove the internal square brackets and specify only the independent variables, x and y.

Comment: In fact I think there is nothing wrong with Mathematica. Plot the function with PlotRange->{-1, 9.5}. You will find an absolute maximum. But there are also a number of local maxima and minima even some imaginary according to the solution by solving the system of derivatives.